# Basic request.getParameter not working

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

home.jsp

```
        <form method="POST" action="Initiater.do">
    <table>
      <tr>
          <td>
           Internal Diameter from FlowAss:
          </td>
           <td>
           <input type="text" id="Id" />
          </td>
          <td>
            Depth:
            </td>
             <td>
  <input type="text" id="Depth" />
            </td>
             <td>
           Units:
            </td>
             <td>
         <select>
         <option value="ft">feet</option>
         <option value="mts">meters</option>
          </select>
            </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
             <td>
          <input type="submit" />
      </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
       </form>
         </body>
             </html>
```

Home.java
public class Home extends HttpServlet {

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,ServletException
{
    System.out.println("in Post");
    String id = (String) request.getParameter("Id");
    String depth = request.getParameter("Depth");
    /*double id =Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("Id"));
    double depth =Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("Depth"));*/
    System.out.println("Id"+id);
    System.out.println("Depth"+depth);
}
```

the servlet Home.java's doPost method is called, the values id and depth are returning nulls when I debug can anyone help me out with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add name attribute to the input tag.

Change

```
  <input type="text" id="Depth" />
  <input type="text" id="Id" />
```

To

```
  <input type="text" id="Depth" name="Depth"/>
  <input type="text" id="Id" name="Id"/>
```

`Request.getParameter` gets data by `name` attribute and not `id`

Comment: hi sanj thanks for your reply and that worked...